# Unable to run rsyslogd as non-root user on CentOS Stream 9

Tags: centos, rhel, rsyslog

When I run rsyslogd as non-root user, I see such errors. However I can do that on RHEL (tried both 8 and 9)

```
[drizzlex@ray myrsyslog]$ rsyslogd -f /home/drizzlex/myrsyslog/myrsyslog.conf -i /home/drizzlex/myrsyslog/run/myrsyslog.pid
rsyslog internal message (3,-2455): could not transfer  the  specified  internal posix  capabilities settings to the kernel, capng_apply=-5
 [v8.2102.0-113.el9 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2455 ]
```

Here is what my conf file looks like

```
[drizzlex@ray myrsyslog]$ cat myrsyslog.conf 
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="6601")

*.* /home/drizzlex/myrsyslog/mylog
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an unfortunate change that forbids anyone from running
`rsyslogd` without root privileges. The code is
[here](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/master/tools/rsyslogd.c#L2203)

```C
if ((capng_rc = capng_apply(CAPNG_SELECT_BOTH)) != 0) {
  LogError(0, RS_RET_LIBCAPNG_ERR,
   "could not transfer  the  specified  internal posix  capabilities "
   "settings to the kernel, capng_apply=%d\n", capng_rc);
  exit(-1);
}
```

but the 13 capabilities required are extensive and most users do not have, for example,
`CAP_SETUID` allows you to change your id.

Clearly, if rsyslogd is started as root, this code is a good idea, dropping
all but the necessary capabilities. However, if you started off as
non-root, or without some of the capabilities, the call of `exit()` is
brutal.

A solution is to download rsyslogd from the sources, and rebuild it without
adding the configure option `--enable-libcap-ng` (which is not there by
default anyway).

Alternatively, you can create a simple shim to dummy up the call to
`capng_apply()` so that it returns 0. Create a file `shim_capng.c` holding:

```C
/*
 * capture calls to a routine and replace with your code
 * https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747252/119298
 * gcc -Wall -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o shim_capng.so shim_capng.c
 * LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/shim_capng.so rsyslogd
 */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cap-ng.h>

int capng_apply(capng_select_t set){
    fprintf(stderr, "not calling real capng_apply\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and compile it with

```bash
gcc -Wall -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o shim_capng.so shim_capng.c
```

You will probably need to install some packages such as `libcap-ng-devel`,
the name depending on your distribution, to have the include file `cap-ng.h`.

Replace your rsyslogd command with

```bash
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/shim_capng.so rsyslogd ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it seems the code change makes it pretty complex for non-root users to use rsyslog. I wonder what is the "proper (easy) way" for non-root users to use it, without recompiling from source or creating a shim.

Comment: And it says in the PR "we will only merge it after the 8.2212.0 scheduled stable has been released", but the rsyslog I tested is 8.2102.0 on both machines (working and not working).

Comment: There is no way for non-root users to run a version of rsyslogd configured with `--enable-libcap-ng`.
You should really be asking "CentOS Stream 9" why they chose to build with this
configuration flag, which is not enabled by default, and perhaps suggest that they should stop doing so.

Comment: I see, thx. How do I check what parameters a rsyslog is configured with?

Comment: What confuses me is it looks like that new flag is not available until 8.2302.0, see [here](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/commit/2348c6424a5e56bdf5f5d534042b44d63458c572) and [here](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/v8-stable/ChangeLog).

However all my tests are done with rsyslog version 8.2102.0 (with different release number). 

I can run as non-root on an Azure RHEL 8.6 VM (rsyslog release is 7.el8_6.1), on an AWS RHEL 9.1 VM (rsyslog release is 113.el9_2)
But I will encounter the error on a local RHEL 9 VM (the rsyslog release is also 113.el9_2)

Comment: I tried to run the [`pscap | grep rsyslogd` command](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/4986) on those hosts, and found that the ones I can run with non-root user all shows full, while the failing ones shows a long list. So it must be that the failing ones were built with the new flag. 

Can someone help me understand why the new code can appear in older version of rsyslog?

Comment: There is no foolproof method to know how rsyslogd was configured. You can guess by looking for debug or other message strings in the binary, or using `ldd` to see what libraries are included, and of course the plugins that are provided. To understand how RedHat chooses its sources and configuration you probably need to ask on a RedHat support forum.